# Read out multiple Data-attribute values HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm currently working on a slider, making use of Mightyslider Plugin.
This plugin stores paramters within the HTML5-data-attr (data-Mightyslider).

```
 <div class="slide" data-mightyslider="
      type: 'image',
      cover: './images/testimage.jpg',   
      title: 'Title of my image', 
      photographer: '',    
      description: 'Proin pellentesque urna nulla.'">
 </div>
```

Is there a solution to read out or store those values separately with use of jQuery? Let's say I need to get the "cover"-parameter out of the data-mightyslider.

This:

```
$("div.mSSlide").each(function() {
      console.log("mSSlide");
      var x = $(this).attr("data-mightyslider");
      console.log(x);
    });
```

is what I had so far and this reads out all the values...

```
mSSlide

cover: './images/testimage.jpg',  
title: 'Title of my image', 
photographer: '', 
description: 'Proin pellentesque urna nulla.'
```

Now I just want e.g. the cover.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over the format the `data` attribute is stored in? If you can amend it to JSON then this becomes trivial. As it is, you'll need to hack the string around and write a lot more code than is necessary.

Comment: I can not change the how the data is stored within the "Data-mightslider" as the plugin doesn't work anymore when I do